# Overriding contextual selectors

Tags: css, inheritance, css-selectors

Is it possible to revert/override attributes from contextual selectors?

```
.card {
  padding-top: 20px;
  ...
}

.card .card-header {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.card .card-header.news {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Is it possible that I can remove the top padding for special elements. Because in the resulting HTML the padding still exists, but I would like to inherit all other styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/v1yxw5n5/27/

Comment: Another thing you can do is add a class on those special and then call it like `.card.special {padding:0}`

Comment: Hi Danko, your answer seems to be the best one. This works like a charm and doesn't create issues with other arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cheat with a negative margin-top:

```css
.card {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.card .card-heading {
    border: solid 1px red;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aemgb75b/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to remove top padding of 'card' which have child with class 'news'. But there is no parent selector in css. But you can do it through jquery. http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

In your case, you can remove padding like this, http://jsfiddle.net/v1yxw5n5/27/

```
<div class="card  news">
<div class="card-heading">
<h4>That is news</h4>
</div>
</div>



.card {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
   }
   .card .card-heading {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0
   }
   .card.news {
    padding-top: 0px;
   }
```

Comment: Maybe you could put the CSS here as well since that's also changed? I shouldn't *have* to refer to the fiddle to see it. That's not how answers work here.

Comment: CSS added. Thanks for correcting me. I am new to posting answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .card .card-heading * {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

in this way you select all elements child of .card .card-heading

Answer (score -1):

You will be able to do that with CSS selector 4 `:has`. But the support is lacking right now

It will look like this:

```
.card:has(.card-heading.news) {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's assuming it will even be available in CSS when it's implemented, which we don't know yet.